# Returning specific Dictionary Values Python

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I return dictionary values with `.values()`? `'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`, so I cannot use `dict.values()[0]` to retrieve the first array [2.96762712e+03, 8.38541299e-01, 1.32466671e-02]

```
dict_values([array([2.96762712e+03, 8.38541299e-01, 1.32466671e-02]), array([2.96762712e+03, 8.38541299e-01, 1.32466671e-02]), array([2.96762712e+03, 8.38541299e-01, 1.32466671e-02]), array([2.96762712e+03, 8.38541299e-01, 1.32466671e-02])])
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with pandas. On `dict_values`, read https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to list prior to indexing:

```
list(dict.values())[0]
```